# Unable to Disable Ubuntu Dock. Already Tried disabling Extention. No replacement dock required

Tags: gnome, customization, gnome-shell-extension, ubuntu-dock, dock

I am trying to remove the visual dock from my GNOME Desktop and these are the things I've already done:

1. I ran this in the terminal

   ```
   gnome-extensions disable ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
   ```
2. Disabled the GNOME Dock from the extensions app
3. Verified that I have it disabled by running

   ```
   gnome-extensions list --disabled
   ```

   And got the output as

   > ding@rastersoft.com
   > ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.comAnd got the output as
   > ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com

However when I hit the <kbd>Super</kbd> key on my keyboard to see all my open windows I still see the dock as attached below:

[As you can see below when I hit the super key I can see all my windows but also my dock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvs8k.jpg)

I am not looking forward to installing additional software to hide the dock. If that is useful.